# Remove Duplicate Special Characters from HTML

Tags: jquery, content-management-system, breadcrumbs

I am working off a custom CMS, and I am having a HUGE issue trying to remove these duplicated special characters from the breadcrumbs of my site so that it reads "Home > Behind The Scenes > Episode 1" instead.

http://www.thejoecozzoshow.com/View/Episode-1

I tried:

```
$('.breadcrumb').html($('.breadcrumb').html().replace(/>  >/g,'>'));
```

But it just doesn't seem to work. Any clue how to resolve this? Thanks!

Comment: Need to target  text nodes, code shown would break the html

Comment: not sure I understand